# Add Char to List

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my code.

```
        List<Char> keyChar = new List<Char>();
        if (keyTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty");
        }
        else
        {

            string key = keyTextBox.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Vaild key: " + key);
            for (int i = 0; i < IOTextBox.Text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 4 == 0)
                {
                    keyChar.Add(keyTextBox.Text[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show(keyChar.ToString());
```

In the output I'm not getting content from the list, but instead I got System.Collections.Generic.List´1[System.Char]

Where did I go wrong? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What do you want to show in the message box?

Comment: Just the content of the keyChar.

Comment: "I want `ToString` to return what I want and not default type name" question is very common. I've marked yours as duplicate of one that have very similar problem and shows a solution.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(new string(keyChar.ToArray()))` you need to use the string constructor that takes an array

Comment: @Jonesy
I tried that and now the output is empty. There is probably error in for loop. I'll try to get rid of it.

Comment: step through the code in the debugger

Comment: It skipped whole if statement. There must be an error.

Comment: I removed if statement without KeyChar.Add... and still no output.